# Typing a higher order function accepting any pure unary function as an optional parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to type a higher order function taking an optional callback which may or may not change the type of its input.

I first tried the following without the option:

```js
type Fn<T, U> = (x: T) => U;
type apply = <T, U>(x: T, f: Fn<T, U>) => U;
const apply:apply = (x, f) => f(x);
```

and it seems to work fine:

```js
const id = <T>(x: T): T => x;
apply(1, id);
apply(1, String);
```

but I get a type error when I try to use anything as a default parameter

```js
type apply = <T, U>(x: T, f?: Fn<T, U>) => U;
```

```js
const apply:apply = (x, f=id) => f(x);
//                      ----
// Type '<T>(x: T) => T' is not assignable to type 'Fn<T, U>'.
//  Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'U'.
//   'U' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'T'
```

```js
const apply:apply = (x, f = (x:number) => x * 2) => f(x);
//                      -----------------------
// Type '(x: number) => number' is not assignable to type 'Fn<T, U>'.
//  Types of parameters 'x' and 'x' are incompatible.
//    Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'number'
```

```js
const apply:apply = (x, f = (x:any):string => x + '') => f(x);
//                      ----------------------------
// Type '(x: any) => string' is not assignable to type 'Fn<T, U>'.
//  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'U'.
//    'U' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'string'
```

I have also tried not using a default parameter and dealing with the optional in the function body

```js
const apply = <T, U>(x: T, f?: Fn<T, U>): U => f ? f(x) : x;
//                                             ------------
// Type 'T | U' is not assignable to type 'U'.
//  'U' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'T | U'.
//    Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'U'.
//      'U' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'T'
```

Can you explain what the language server believes is a problem here?

How could I express this type ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For generic functions, the *caller* specifies the type parameter, not the *implementation*.  Often this specification happens automatically via type inference, but it is still technically in the control of the caller and not the implementer.

Let's look at this implementation of `apply()`:

```
const apply = <T, U>(x: T, f?: Fn<T, U>): U => f ? f(x) : x;
```

---

If the caller calls `apply()` with two function parameters, everything is fine:

```
apply(Math.random(), (x: number) => String(x)).toUpperCase();
```

Here, the compiler infers `number` for `T` and `string` for `U`.  It is equivalent to the caller writing this:

```
apply<number, string>(Math.random(), (x: number) => String(x)).toUpperCase(); // okay
```

If the caller tried to pass the same function parameters in while specifying incompatible type parameters, the compiler would warn:

```
apply<string, number>(Math.random(), (x: number) => String(x)).toUpperCase(); // error!
// -----------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~     ---------------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~
// number is not string                 number has no toUpperCase
```

So everything is as it should be.

---

If the caller calls `apply()` with just one function parameter, though, issues can occur:

```
apply(Math.random());
```

Here, the compiler infers `number` for `T`, but there is nothing from which to infer `U`.  Thus inference fails and the compiler falls back to [the `unknown` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#unknown).  So it's equivalent to doing this:

```
apply<number, unknown>(Math.random()); // okay
```

That's still all right, since treating the output as `unknown` is safe... albeit useless.  But watch what happens when the caller manually specifies other types for `U`:

```
apply<number, string>(Math.random()).toUpperCase(); // okay?!
// RUNTIME ERROR!!!
```

The caller has basically said "please return a `string`", which is allowable.  The caller is in control of what `T` and `U` are.  And so the compiler thinks that is what has occurred.  Thus there is no compiler error when you try to call the output's `toUpperCase()` method.  But at runtime this explodes.

---

**Because the implementation is wrong.**  And the compiler was telling you that:

```
const apply = <T, U>(x: T, f?: Fn<T, U>): U => f ? f(x) : x;
//                                             ------------
// Type 'T | U' is not assignable to type 'U'.
//  'U' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'T | U'.
//    Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'U'.
//      'U' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'T'
```

It's saying that you are *claiming* to return a value of type `U`, but in actuality are returning a value of type `T | U`.  If it turns out that `U` is some arbitrary type (like `string` in the example), and doesn't happen to coincide with `T` (like `number` in the example), then you are not fulfilling the contract, and bad things can happen (like runtime errors when people call your function).

---

So, what can be done?  If you are not really concerned with the (admittedly unlikely) possibility that a caller will manually specify `U` with some random type and expect magic to happen, you can just use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler not to worry about the possible issue:

```
const applyAssert = <T, U = T>(x: T, f?: Fn<T, U>): U => f ? f(x) : x as any as U;
```

By `x as any as U` I'm saying "yes, I know that you can't be sure that `x` is a `U`, but I'm telling you that it will be."  Furthermore I gave `U` a [default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) of `T` (via `U = T`) so that when the compiler cannot infer `U` it will fall back to the default.  This gives you the presumably intended behavior here:

```
applyAssert(Math.random()).toFixed(2); // okay
// const applyAssert: <number, number>(x: number, f?: Fn<number, number> | undefined) => number
```

But remember, it does not protect against evil/confused callers:

```
applyAssert<number, string>(Math.random()).toUpperCase(); // okay?!
```

---

If you want to make `apply()` completely type safe, it is more complicated, and you still have to use something like assertions to help the compiler along.  Perhaps something like this:

```
function applyOverload<T>(x: T): T;
function applyOverload<T, U>(x: T, f: Fn<T, U>): U;
function applyOverload(x: any, f?: Function) {
    return f ? f(x) : x;
}
```

This is an [overloaded function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) with two distinct call signatures: one for a single argument, and one for two arguments.  If you call it with one argument, there is no `U`, only `T`.  So it becomes impossible to call it incorrectly, even manually:

```
applyOverload(Math.random(), (x: number) => String(x)).toUpperCase(); // okay
applyOverload(Math.random()).toFixed(); // okay
applyOverload<number, string>(Math.random()); // error! expect 2 arguments, but got 1
```

As for why this is "like assertions", overloaded functions are not generally safe.  Implementations are checked loosely. Above, you can see that the implementation takes arguments of the weak types `any` and `Function` and returns a value of type `any`.  It happens that we implemented the function properly, but the compiler wouldn't notice or care if we did something weird here:

```
function applyBadOverload<T>(x: T): T;
function applyBadOverload<T, U>(x: T, f: Fn<T, U>): U;
function applyBadOverload(x: any, f?: Function) {
    return "oopsie"; // no error
}
```

So you need to be careful either way.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-WGlTGyDmy3WqxQMEqADWbBAyZ0IAQCeaaFLpuzYrzUtl8sVJeD6qCFd11aNJobVptLZiptOKlOAEJRlkDwfsAA-U9n89nhKH69HqAX++jIenKo1OpafspZJPqAHS2wgF1qaFpWt2BgiqOkoFvKVijHYmgOro-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)

Comment: Thank you, that was very enlightening! I will have to ponder the addition of optional arguments to my APIs.